Intersection of dense sets in a Banach space

Suppose $(X, ||.||_X)$ be a Banach space. Let $Y, Z$ be two dense subsets.

We know that $Y \cap Z$ may not be dense in $X$ (rationals and irrationals on real line) even if $Y \cap Z \neq \emptyset$ (rationals $\cup \sqrt{2}$ and irrationals on real line).
But if $Y \cap Z$ contains an open subset of $(X, ||.||_X)$, can we say $Y \cap Z$ is dense? No: we can take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean norm, $Y=\mathbb{Q} \cup (0,2)$ and $Z=(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cup (0,2)$.
From the links below we can see,

it is a sufficient criterion for $Y \cap Z$ to be a dense subset of $(X, ||.||_X)$ if either of $Y$ or $Z$ is open in $X$. But is it also a necessary criterion ?

Any reference to the proof of this fact ?
Some related links can be found below:

Dense subset of two Banach spaces also dense in the intersection

In a complete metric space with no isolated points, any countable intersection of open dense sets is uncountable?

Intersection of an open dense set and any dense set is dense.

If $A, B$ are open dense subsets of a metric space $X$, is their intersection dense??



You can have $Y=Z$ dense but not open

What did you try? (Keep it simple, take $X=\Bbb R$.)
